# Reload a tab after dismissing a view

Tags: ios, tabs

There are two views in a `tabbarviewcontroller`. And the first tab has its view controller called myViewController which contain its `IBOutlet`. Pressing the button on the first view will present a view controller. After dismissing the view and back to the tab, the `viewWillAppear` of myViewController won't be called,but `viewWillAppear` of `tabbarviewcontroller` will. I need to reload the information on the first tab. If I use `viewWillAppear` in `tabbarviewcontraller`, how do I change the values of these property in myViewController?  If anyone has idea ? Thanks.

Comment: add update code in viewWillAppear method

Comment: Just write your reload data code in view will appear function. it will call again when presented view dismissed. Or make conditions for prevent other cases if you have...

Comment: @kirtimali But the tab has its view controller called myViewController which contain its IBOutlet. If you call viewWillAppear in tabbarviewcontraller, how do you change the values of these property in myViewController?

Comment: you set bool variable when view is dismiss

Comment: @kirtimali Could you explain in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call viewWillAppear of the viewController, you can add this to viewWillAppear of the TabBar

```
for (UIViewController *viewController in  tabBarController.viewControllers)
{
    [viewController viewWillAppear:YES]
}
```